# how to replace a particular div tag with a span tag using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<div class="c45 c45v0">
    <p><span>J</span>oseph DeSimone made a bold move back</p>
</div>
```

I want to replace `<div class="c45 c45v0">` with a `<span class="c6 c77">`.

```
<span class="c6 c77">
    <p><span>J</span>oseph DeSimone made a bold move back</p>
</span>
```

I tried to use below code to replace but i'm unable to replace it. Would anyone please help me to solve this.

```
if (elements.select("div.c45.c45v0").size()>0) {
    if (!elements.select("div.c45.c45v0").isEmpty()) {
        elements.tagName("span.c6.c77");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on fact that `elements` is object *from* which you are selecting `div.c45.c45v0` it looks like it is not *the* searched element, but only *containing* one so manipulating it doesn't make much sense. Second thing is that you don't wanted to set class attributes via `tagName`. You need to set tag via `tagName` but `class` attribute either via `.attr("class", "c6 c77")` or via series of `addClass` (for new classes) and `removeClass`(for previous classes).

Demo:

```
String html =
        "<div class=\"c45 c45v0\">\n" +
        "    <p><span>J</span>oseph DeSimone made a bold move back</p>\n" +
        "</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

//here 'elements' contain only div.c45.c45v0 elements *from* entire document (doc)
Elements elements = doc.select("div.c45.c45v0");
System.out.println(elements);

//now we can manipulate those selected elements
elements.tagName("span");
elements.attr("class", "c6 c77");
System.out.println("---------------");
System.out.println(elements);
```

Output:

```
<div class="c45 c45v0"> 
 <p><span>J</span>oseph DeSimone made a bold move back</p> 
</div>
---------------
<span class="c6 c77"> <p><span>J</span>oseph DeSimone made a bold move back</p> </span>
```